# Create a device in Azure IoT Hub by Terraform

Tags: azure, automation, terraform, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to automate setting up of IoT Hub. But I am not able to find any code related to creating a device in the IoT Hub. I found the below command:

```
resource “azurerm_iothub_device” “example” {
    name = “device_name” iothub_name = azurerm_iothub.iothub12.name
}
```

But it does not seem to be valid.
I have installed the extensions *azure IoT Hub* and *IoT Device Workbench*.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please ignore typo "enter code here"

Comment: Re *"Please ignore typo "enter code here""*: Does "edit" stir anything in you? You can change your post. Stack Overflow is not a forum. And posts are not cast in stone after the initial publication (unlike traditional forums).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, i am very much aware that posts are not cast in stone nor in iron. what i am not aware of is, to edit the post, as it is my 1st post. I think you could have guided me how to edit the post rather than making fun of it. It is professional forum, and i respect it and hence request you to be professional here. thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [EliiseS](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12604), as of now, support for IoT Hub device creation using Terraform is not available.

Comment: Not sure why this is posted as an answer, rather than a comment - it's just a link to another site. This is not a valid answer (and if that link rots and dies, the answer is unusable).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I use is to use a local provisioner. I use it in my iothub resource for creation. The downside is that it only works on resource creation (or deletion) - so if devices need to be updated at a later stage without recreating the IoT hub you would need to create a new resource with said provisioner.
My provisioner:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "${path.module}/create-iot-device.sh ${azurerm_iothub.<your-resource-name>.name}" 
}
```

And the create-iot-device.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
az iot hub device-identity create --device-id dev-1 --hub-name $1
```